# R tgp package installation under MKL environment

Tags: r, dependencies, conda, lapack, openblas

I am working on a server to which I don't have admin rights.
I linked R to MKL for fast linear algebra using a Conda environment following these steps:
[Conda install r-essentials with MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834940/conda-install-r-essentials-with-mkl)

The linking of R to MKL was successful, the output for `R InfoSession()` under the activated environment is as follows:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default BLAS/LAPACK:
/userInfo/miniconda3/envs/R_mkl/lib/libmkl_rt.so

locale: [1] C

attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.6.3
```

My goal is to install and use the R tgp package under this environment.
When trying to install the tgp package with `R CMD INSTALL`, the installation fails with the following **error**

> libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory

This installation succeeds when using the 'regular' R version that is not linked to MKL.
This error concerns OpenBlas while I want to use MKL.

I hope anyone knows how to fix these dependencies knowing I do not have admin rights.

Comment: Please provide more details about the environment. For example, add the output of `conda list -n R_mkl '(r-base|tgp|blas|lapack|mkl)'` to the question body. Also, where are you getting the `tgp` package from? It doesn't appear to be on Conda Forge.

Comment: Also, the environment suggested in that answer is outdated. Unless you require specific versions of packages that are only available for R 3.6, you should be using R 4.1 or 4.2.

Comment: I updated [the referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58845790/570918). Still won't solve your `tgp` issue, but I've put in [a PR to add it to Conda Forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/21703) which should resolve that (typically a 24 hour turnaround).

Comment: The `r-tgp` package should be available through `conda-forge` channel now.